# Does Visual Studio Code use .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, visual-studio-code

i'm new to Visual Studio Code and may be my question is stupid. I know that VSC is MS tool but how does it cope with .htaccess file rewrite rules ?

I mean VSC has plugins to develop PHP application, to debug PHP but what about testing and using .htaccess file ?

In order to dev & test my PHP dev i was thinking to use VSC under linux but i'm not sure my .htaccess will be read and used by VSC during testing/debugging phase.

thx

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio Code has a lot of plugins to recognize a lot of different file types. ApacheConf allow you show nice your .htaccess files, autocomplete, etc.

[image]

This is the link to the plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-apache

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about using .htaccess files with the PHP Server plugin, I was investigating about that and I think it is not possible. Here you have a similar question, answered by the developer of the plugin:

https://github.com/brapifra/vscode-phpserver/issues/19

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Please consider quoting the relevant part of the linked content to help other users of the site.