# How can I download pdf resume using the download button I created on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a download button on HTML to download my resume. I created the button it does download my resume, however, it says 'Failed- no file' for the downloaded cv

Here is my Code:

```
<div className="header__buttons">
    <a href="/images/cv.pdf" className="btn btn-outline" download>Download Resume
    </a>
</div>
```

This is how it looks like: [image: No File CV].

This is how my project is structured: [image: project]:

Comment: check the file location path

Comment: Try `images/cv.pdf` or `./images/cv.pdf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem earlier. It only worked when I imported the file to my component.

```
import MyResume from '../assets/resume.pdf'

<a :href="MyResume" alt="resume" download>download resume</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be experiencing a `mod_rewrite` error for the server. Edit your htaccess file like the example below. For more detailed information: [Apache Indexes restrict download file types](https://serverfault.com/questions/841446/apache-indexes-restrict-download-file-types/841461#841461)

```
<Directory "/var/www/data01">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    IndexOptions ShowForbidden
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride all

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule !(\.txt$|^$) - [NS,F]
</Directory>
```

Comment: Where do I add this

Comment: @Coni You have to edit and add this to the `.htaccess` file. Check out the link.

Comment: How do you access it? In this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559695/does-visual-studio-code-use-htaccess   it says use apache but I still cannot see it after installing apache

Answer (score -1):

try without the first slash:

```
href="images/cv.pdf"
```

Answer (score -2):

Does adding a dot before the first slash work?

```
href="./images/cv.pdf"
```

Comment: Nope, tried like that. I even put pdf into the same folder with the file I am executing still no hope

Comment: Just to be sure that its not a filepath problem, right-click on the cv.pdf file and select "Copy Relative Path", then past that in as the link.